# How is / Why is not CiviRules triggering actions for <target> contacts with outbound email?

Tags: civirules

I need a tip with setting up a CiviRule for actions (adding tags etc. to target contacts) when an outgoing email activity is added. Civirules  triggers only for source contacts even if the trigger is set to all contacts.

(Used CiviRules 2.32+ on drupal 8 and latest CiviCRM )